# How to display the last char of the NSString *

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to ask a question about the NSString * in objective C. I have an string read from somewhere and I would like to get the last char of that NSString object? I used to try the objectAtIndex, but I don't know what to get the index. What should I type? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
unichar lastChar = [yourString characterAtIndex:[yourString length] - 1];
```

or if you want it as an `NSString`:

```
NSString *lastChar = [yourString substringFromIndex:[yourString length] - 1];
```

Comment: Caveat: This will produce broken text if the string ends with a combined character sequence or surrogate pair.

Comment: This should also crash if a string is empty

Comment: Presumably one would check that first.